# What's the reason for the memory access error?

Tags: c

I am a student learning C. and I am currently learning about strings.

So I decided to make a short code generating a password according to the URL I type in.
The problem is I constantly get this memory error whenever I try debugging, and I just can't seem to find out the reason for it.

The following line of code is where the error occurs.

```
scanf("%s", address);

for (i = 0; address[i+7] = "."; i++)
{
    address[i + 7] = address_name[i];
}
```

The code reads the URL address (ex. http://google.com) and saves only the name part (google) excluding the "http://" and ".com" part. So the for loop should move each letter to address_name until the dot from .com shows up, but I am getting an error here.

An explanation for a beginner would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The value of `address[i+7] = "."` will be some implementation-defined value (the pointer converted from the string literal converted to an integer) When it isn't zero, the loop goes infinitely.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is equality operator, `"."` is a string literal, `'.'` is a character literal. Maybe you meant `address[i+7] != '.'`

Comment: There is too much wrong or unexplained here. How is `address` declared? What is `address_name`? Why is data being copied from `address_name` into the buffer that was used for getting user input, `address`? Why is `7` used?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the loop condition:

```
address[i+7] = "."
```

First, you're using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`.  This means the result of the expression will be whatever was assigned, which in this case is the address of a string literal.  Because this is a non-zero value, the condition will always be true resulting in an infinite loop.

Also, the elements of `address` are (presumably) of type `char` but `"."` is a string literal.  You want to use single quotes for a character literal.

Finally, you want the loop to continue as long as the current character is *not* a `.` so you want the `!=` operator instead of the `==` operator.

So the condition should be:

```
address[i+7] != '.'
```

Comment: @J... Given that the OP is a beginner and there were multiple problems, I don't think it qualifies as a typo.

Comment: The result of `address[i+7] = "."` is not “the address of a string literal”; it is not the right-hand side of the `=`. It is the value assigned, which is the address converted to the type of `address[i+7]`. Given the presumption this is a `char`, the result is implementation-defined and could be zero.